# How to put picker component inside a page that have a tab navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native

i need some help. I am new to Native React. I have a created a tab navigator in react native.  I would like to put a picker in one of the pages. But i am not too sure how to do it. I have both code on my Tab navigator  and a code for picker as well.

**My codes for Tab navigator:**

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import { Text, View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Picker} from 'react-native';
 import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
 import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
 import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
 import  Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

 export default function App() {
   return (
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Tab.Navigator  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Home') {
              iconName = focused
                ? 'ios-information-circle'
                : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
            } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'black',
          inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }}
        >
         <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
         <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
       </Tab.Navigator>
     </NavigationContainer>
   );
  }


function DetailsScreen() {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Details!</Text>
  </View>
);
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
 const [value, onChangeText]= React.useState('')
 return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
     <Text>Tab 1</Text>
     <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor:'black', borderWidth: 1, color: 'red', borderRadius:10}} placeholder="Type Here" onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)} value={value}/>
     <Button
     title="Go to Settings"
     onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
   />



   </View>
 );
}

function SettingsScreen({navigation}) {
 return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
     <Text>Tab 2</Text>
     <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
   </View>
 );
}



const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
return (
  <HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
);
}

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();

function SettingsStackScreen() {
return (
  <SettingsStack.Navigator>
    <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    <SettingsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
  </SettingsStack.Navigator>
);
}
```

**My Code for a picker(simple)**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import { Text, View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Picker} from 'react-native';
 import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
 import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
 import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
 import  Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
 import RNPPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';


 export default class SwitchExample extends Component {
    state = {
        choosenIndex: 0
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Picker Example</Text>
                <Picker style={styles.pickerStyle}
                        selectedValue={this.state.language}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemPosition) =>
                            this.setState({language: itemValue, choosenIndex: itemPosition})}
                    >
                    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
                    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
                    <Picker.Item label="React Native" value="rn" />
                </Picker>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}> {"Index ="+this.state.choosenIndex}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
     container: {
         flex: 1,
         alignItems: 'center',
         justifyContent: 'center',
     },
    textStyle:{
        margin: 24,
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    pickerStyle:{
        height: 150,
        width: "80%",
        color: '#344953',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
})
```

Comment: what picker you want? and share your code & error screen

Comment: a normal picker is fine. I have updated my post. There is technically no errors, but i dont know how to combined these 2 codes together, so that the final product, the Home tab will have a picker.